# php for two variables can't multiply

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I have a simple for loop with 2 variables.
I want $m variable to be multiplied by 1.5 in every pass. 
But $m value remains the same. Here's the code:

```
for ($i=0, $m=60 ; $i < 30; $i++, $m*1.5) { 
    echo $i." ".$m." " .$m/4 ."<br>";
}
```

The result is:

```
0 60 15
1 60 15
2 60 15
3 60 15
4 60 15
5 60 15
6 60 15
7 60 15
8 60 15
9 60 15
```

Answer (score 1):

You are `echo`ing $m and not $m*1.5.
`$i++ is the same as $i =$i +1.`
So the code at the end of the `for` is the one that is evaluated after every loop; $m is multiplied by 1.5 but the result isn't stored in it.
To fix this change:
`$m* 1.5.`
To:
`$m =$m*1.5`

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i=0, $m=60 ; $i < 30; $i++, $m*=1.5) { 
echo $i." ".$m." " .$m/4 ."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write

```
$m*=1.5
```

instead of `$m*1.5`.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have forgotten that `$i++` is shorhand for `$i = $i + 1`.

What you need is the following:

```
for ($i=0, $m=60 ; $i < 30; $i++, $m = $m*1.5) { 
    echo $i." ".$m." " .$m/4 ."<br>";
}
```

A shorter form of the same thing is:

```
for ($i=0, $m=60 ; $i < 30; $i++, $m *= 1.5) { 
    echo $i." ".$m." " .$m/4 ."<br>";
}
```